# Loop for a ANOVA function in Python

Tags: python, loops, anova

I have big data, with these columns:

```
columns=['FES_1', 'FES_2', 'FES_3', 'FES_4', 'FES_5',
   'FES_6', 'FES_7', 'FES_T', 'FES_S', 'IPAQ_1a', 'IPAQ_1b', 'IPAQ_2a',
   'IPAQ_2b', 'IPAQ_3a', 'IPAQ_3b', 'IPAQ_4a', 'IPAQ_4b', 'IPAQ_S',
   'TMT_timeA', 'TMT_errorsA', 'TMT_timeB', 'TMT_errorsB', 'Best_1',
   'Best_2', 'Best_3l', 'Best_3r', 'Best_4', 'Best_5', 'Best_6l',
   'Best_6r', 'Best_7', 'Best_8', 'Best_9', 'Best_10', 'Best_11',
   'Best_12', 'Best_13', 'Best_14', 'Best_T', 'COPmeanX',
   'COPmeanY', 'COPstdX', 'COPstdY', 'COParea', 'COPveloX', 'COPveloY',
   'COPmaxX', 'COPmaxY', 'COPrmsX', 'COPrmsY', 'PDFcopx15', 'PDFcopy15',
   'PDFcopx2', 'PDFcopy2', 'COPx01', 'COPy01', 'rateCOPx01', 'rateCOPy01',
   'COPxmax', 'COPymax', 'Fall']
```

I have to run this code, to see each value:

```
model = smf.ols("FES_1 ~ C(AgeGroup) + C(Surface) + C(Vision) + C(AgeGroup)*C(Surface)*C(Vision)", data=data).fit() 
aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
aov_table
```

|sum_sq   |df       |F  |PR(>F)|

|C(AgeGroup)   |0.508776   |1.0 |0.225681   |0.634799

|C(Surface)   |0.003008    |1.0 |0.001334   |0.970864

|C(Vision)   |0.000092     |1.0 |0.000041   |0.994899

|C(AgeGroup):C(Surface)   |0.002167    |1.0  |0.000961   |0.975272

|C(AgeGroup):C(Vision)   |0.000578     |1.0   |0.000256   |0.987228

|C(Surface):C(Vision)   |0.011279      |1.0   |0.005003   |0.943619

|C(AgeGroup):C(Surface):C(Vision)   |0.016296   |1.0   |0.007229   |0.932253

|Residual   |4332.953853   |1922.0   |NaN   |NaN

(This table is horrible, but this is the main idea).

So, I have to do a loop, to run all the columns.
And, when I do this loop, I want to check all the tables, and print just the PR(>F) that have a value less than 0.1.

This is possible?